# Do modern browsers still need a svg definition file for font-awesome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-face

My code is using the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Is it safe for me to assume that if I target IE9 and later that there will be no need for the svg or opentype ? The reason I am asking is because I notice the site that I use to make custom icons now comments out the svg.

```
//    url('@{FontAwesomePath}/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.0.1') format('svg');
//  src: url('@{FontAwesomePath}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype');
```

Comment: All major modern web browsers—including Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer 9 and 10, Google Chrome, Opera, and Safari—have at least some degree of support for SVG and can render the markup directly.

Comment: Yeah but wait. The custom generator I use does not create svg so I'm asking if the svg file is no longer needed.

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support? Only IE?

Answer (score 2):

SVG was probably to support support for iOS < 5.0.
Modern browsers only need WOFF.

See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26992/if-i-have-only-woff-and-eot-what-browsers-am-i-supporting-with-font-face